# Update FK on php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a form where i would want to update some records, all the fields are working properly but the FK (which is `id_colaborador`)
I want also to input the name of the user (`nome`) instead of the `id`
I have the following `UPDATE` code but it just ignores the FK field i don't know why...

```
$sql = "UPDATE ativos  SET ativo = ?, comentario = ?, data_aquisicao = ?, localizacao = ?, fabricante = ?, modelo = ?, imei = ?, 
        numero_serie = ?, ativo_sap = ?, anexo_a = ?, evento = ?, data_evento = ?, id_colaborador = ? WHERE id_ativo = ?";
```

And for the input of `id_colaborador` I have this:

```
<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($id_colaboradorError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label"><strong>Colaborador<span style="color: red">*</span></strong></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input  type="text"  placeholder="Colaborador"  value="<?php echo !empty($id_colaborador)?$id_colaborador:'';?>">       
                        <?php if (!empty($id_colaboradorError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $id_colaboradorError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to put the `nome` value into the `id_colaborador` field?

Comment: Yes, I manage to do it on the `Create` page but idk why I can't here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form field is missing the **name** attribute. If the rest of your code expects the name to be `id_colaborador`, you'd add it like this:

```
<input name="id_colaborador" type="text"  placeholder="Colaborador"  value="<?php echo !empty($id_colaborador)?$id_colaborador:'';?>">
```

For the second part of the question, the answer depends on how many users you have.

If you only have a few, you can list them all in a `SELECT` box, where the value of the option is the numeric id.

If you have many users, you can use an autocomplete text field for the name and a hidden text input for the ID. When a is selected via autocomplete, you'd fill the hidden input with the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, but it still doesn't work.. it keep ignoring the input :/

Comment: Nvm It worked sorry was my bad... Thanks!!
And the second part.. well Now a just have a few but furter it will have a lot of users, and then I just need to hide the `id_colaborador` field and write the name I want, right? Thanks once again!